# .env is not being detected in Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have done `pip install python-dotenv` and then created a `.env` file in the same folder as the `settings.py`. The values from the `.env` is not working.

settings:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

.env file:

```
SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey
```

What should I do?

Comment: did you loaded the env?

Comment: yes the env was already active

Comment: Can you show how did you do that?

Comment: source env/Scripts/activate (running on bash)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the package [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to load configuration from a `.env` file

After installing the package, within your Django project's `manage.py` file, add the following line to load the environment variables from the .env file:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Define the path to your .env file
dotenv_path = "path-to-your-dot-env"

# Load environment variables from the .env file
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
```

For example

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Assuming both the .env file and manage.py are in the same directory
dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".env")
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "python-decouple"
first, install python-decouple package

```
"pip install python-decouple"
```

then, use it like this:

```
from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```